# Objective-C: How to pass an object as a block argument to a method that expects its base class?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

If I have the following objects:

```
@interface Simple : NSObject

@end

@interface Complex : Simple

@end
```

And another object like:

```
@interface Test : NSObject 

+(void) doSomething:(void (^)(Simple*)) obj;

@end
```

Everything works if I call the method like:

```
[Test doSomething:^(Simple * obj) {

}];
```

When I try instead to call it like:

```
[Test doSomething:^(Complex * obj) {

}];
```

The compiler says that:

`Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(Complex *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(Simple *__strong)'`

Because `Complex` extends `Simple`, I thought this would work, like in Java.

Is there a way to achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the Blocks API.  If you'd like to,  you have the option of completely forgoing type safety and declaring the block as:

```
+(void) doSomething:(void (^)(id)) obj;
```

Which allows you to set the class of the arguments of the block.  But again, this is **completely unsafe**, type-wise.

Comment: Is this actually unfortunate?  `Test` asks for and gets a reference to a block with a signature that says the block takes an argument of type `Simple`.  Handing it a block that takes a subtype `Complex` might mean that `Test` could make an illegal call by calling the block with a different subclass of `Simple`.

Comment: I'm just saying that it seems reasonable to call this a breach of contract.  If it's not, the compiler can't know if any call in `Test` to execute the block has a legal parameter.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell Sorry, I didn't quite read through what you'd written.  Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `id` instead of `Complex *` or `Simple *`. Block parameter types are handled differently than method parameter types (thanks @CodaFi)